# Использование словаря ресурсов на странице UWP

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

Возникло затруднение с использованием ресурсов. Допустим есть словарь присоединенный к ресурсам

```
<Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="ResourceDictionaries/AuthenticationDictionary.xaml"/>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
```

Данный словарь применялся для 3х страниц, автоматически применяясь к каждому элементу без явного указания.
Теперь требуется включить другой словарь для других страниц. Как это можно сделать, без явных указаний для каждого контрола какой именно словарь использовать, по типу `Background="{StaticResource buttonBrush}"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Смотрите.

Стили, определённые в `Application.Resources`, действуют на всё приложение.
Стили, определённые в ресурсах страницы, действуют на данной странице, и перекрывают *соответствующие* ресурсы из `Application.Resources`.

Пример: если в `Application.Resources` определены стили

```
<Style TargetType="Button">...</Style>
<Style TargetType="TextBox" x:Key="TBStyle">...</Style>
```

то на странице будут действовать они тоже. Но если вы в ресурсах страницы переопределите

```
<Style TargetType="Button">...</Style>
```

— то действовать будет новый стлиь, а стиль `TextBox`'а останется тот же, из `Application.Resources`.

Также, вы можете перекрыть стили аналогичным образом внутри любого контейнера внутри страницы. Более «внутреннее» переопределение всегда сильнее более «внешнего».

---

Таким образом, вам нужно перекрыть в ресурсах страницы те стили из `Application.Resources`, которые вам не подходят.

Comment: С этим разобрался. А как тогда привязать к странице целый словарь? Я пробовал через <Page.Resources> <ResourceDictionary Source="ResourceDictionaries/MainDictionary.xaml" x:Key="MainDictionary"/> </Page.Resources> Но он ругается на Source. Возможно привязка словаря к отдельной странице происходит как то не там?

Comment: @АртёмКиргизов: Вы правильно привязываете. А как именно ругается? По идее, вам не нужен `x:Key`, может, ругается на него?

Comment: Проблема заключалась в том, что он искал файл со словарем в той же папке. Проблема решилась после того как привел к виду: <ResourceDictionary Source="../../../ResourceDictionaries/AuthenticationDictionary.xaml"/>. У меня ещё один вопрос. Если я хочу в Page.Resources указать дополнительные стили, то он начинается ругаться на включенный словарь. Как я понимаю, подключая словари, мы обязаны все стили реализовывать в нем?

Comment: @АртёмКиргизов: Пока вы не скажете, как именно ругается, я не смогу догадаться, в чём дело. Покажите ваш код и сообщение об ошибке.

Comment: <Page.Resources>
  <Style TargetType="Grid" x:Key="GridAnimation">
  </Style>
  <ResourceDictionary Source="/ResourceDictionaries/AuthenticationDictionary.xaml" x:Key="dict"/>
 </Page.Resources> В общем я подключил словарь к в дополнении к стилям, он сначала ругался на словарь, у которого нет ключа. После добавления ключа он ругался на свойство Source у словаря. Но после перекомпиляции проекта проблема исчезла. Но теперь другой вопрос: как использовать стиль словаря для элемента по ключу, в данном случае "dict"?

Comment: @АртёмКиргизов: Не-не, так нельзя. Нужно так: https://pastebin.com/aaUUA0Bz

Comment: Спасибо большое, вы мне очень помогли. Вопрос исчерпан

Comment: @АртёмКиргизов: Пожалуйста, рад был помочь!